# Help I haved no wireless sinced installing updates on 12.10

Tags: wireless

Obviously a step by step guide would be very helpful please as I'm new to this inputting code lark.

I had a wireless connection when I installed ubuntu 12.10 from the cd once it installed it suggested there was 126 updates so I installed those and my wireless connection has stopped.

I've tried looking at other posts but find that I end going round in circles, what I'm after is the answer in a step be step format without having go around the houses looking at a thousand other posts with similar problems.

Below is what popped up in the terminal hopefully theres some kind person out there that understands what the problem is....

```
bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-5.100.82.112+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-25-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
```

Thanks for your help

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to disable driver for your wireless card in Settings -> Source Software -> additional drivers (sorry if the path is not correct, i have Ubuntu in italian) and then restart. For me it worked.

Comment: Hi Sasha how do I do that?

Comment: Search for Ubuntu Software Center, then go to Modify and at the bottom you will find Source software. Go under the menu Additional drivers and try to disable the drivers for your wireless card.

Answer (score 1):

```
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

This means that kernel headers are required but missing to build this driver. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install -reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Chili555 You are a true hero thank you so much I am wireless and happy!

Comment: Glad it's working.